# Difference between "pip install sompackage and python pip install somepackage" commands

Tags: python, pip, django

I had to install **Sphinx** on Ubuntu for use with **python (django)** and I came across this two commands: `pip install Sphinx`, and then I saw this too `python -m pip install Sphinx`.

Are there any difference as to where **Sphinx** will be installed as I want to be able to use Sphinx globally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/bin/pip` is just a Python script that invokes the `pip` module using [the `load_entry_point` function](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#convenience-api). Therefore, the following are (mostly) equivalent:

```
python -m pip ...
pip ...
```

See [What's the difference between pip install and python -m pip install? on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25749621/2072269) for details.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have multiple versions of python installed, these two commands do the same. You can test this by doing

`pip list` and `python -m pip list` it should output the same packages.

If you do have multiple versions installed, either keep the preferred one on you path or call it directly with its absolute path i.e. `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Hi John, I have two versions of python so I usually do this "pip3"[for python 3.4] or "pip[for python 2.7].